# Emacs selection by indentation

Tags: emacs, selection, sublimetext

In Sublime Text one can select a block of code based on indentation:
(**`Selection -> Expand Selection to Indentation`**)

For example in the following block of code and cursor at position being
marked here:

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id='link-main'><a href='#'>Main site</a></li>
            <li class='stupid'><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>
            <li class='stupid'><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <a href="random link"></a><CURSOR_HERE>
            <div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</header>
```

This will result in this selection (marked by `<SELECTION>` and `</SELECTION>`)

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
 <SELECTION><li id='link-main'><a href='#'>Main site</a></li>
            <li class='stupid'><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>
            <li class='stupid'><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <a href="random link"></a>
            <div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li></SELECTION>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</header>
```

How can I achieve the same thing using emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil), here's an evil plugin [evil-indent-textobject](https://github.com/cofi/evil-indent-textobject) can select (or yank/delete) a block based of indentation.

Comment: This is almost it, but It will not select any "child" indentation and will stop on first <div> line.

Comment: Redefine function `evil-indent--same-indent-range` from evil-indent-textobject.el to [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/Dewdrops/e5602ff6b410954fed0b) may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about indentation-based selection, but [expand region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) does semantic expansion:

> Expand region increases the selected region by semantic units. Just keep pressing the key until it selects what you want.

Expand region is [available on MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/expand-region).

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun ar-backward-indent ()
  "Go backward same or deeper levels of indentation. "
  (interactive)
  (let ((orig (point))
    (indent (progn (back-to-indentation) (current-column)))
    (last (point)))
    (while (and (not (bobp))(forward-line -1) (progn (back-to-indentation) (<= indent (current-indentation))))
      (setq last (point)))
    (goto-char last)))

(defun ar-forward-indent ()
  "Go backward same or deeper levels of indentation. "
  (interactive)
  (let ((indent (progn (back-to-indentation) (current-column)))
    last)
    (while
    (and (not (eobp)) (forward-line 1) (progn (back-to-indentation) (<= indent (current-indentation))))
      (setq last (line-end-position)))
    (goto-char last)))

(defun ar-mark-indent-level ()
  "Mark lines around point where indentation is equal or deeper. "
  (interactive)
  (let ((orig (point)))
    (ar-backward-indent)
    (push-mark (point) t)
    (goto-char orig)
    (ar-forward-indent)))
```

Source: https://github.com/andreas-roehler/subroutines

Answer (score 0):

First we have to check if point is on a line with 0 indentation, if it is select whole buffer.

If point is on a line with some indentation, select all lines which have **same or less** indentation.

```
(defun expand-to-indentation ()
  "Select surrounding lines with current indentation."
  (interactive)
  (let ((indentation (current-indentation)))
    (if (= indentation 0)
        (mark-whole-buffer)
      (while (<= indentation (current-indentation))
        (forward-line -1))
      (forward-line 1)
      (push-mark (point) nil t)
      (while (<= indentation (current-indentation))
        (forward-line 1))   
      (backward-char))))
```

You can call this function interactively or you can bind it to any key.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ChillarAnand 's answer, I'm using below for myself:

```
(defun mark-current-indentation (&optional ARG)
  "Select surrounding lines with current indentation.
if ARG is 'C-u', mark forward; if ARG is 'C-u C-u', mark backward."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((is-forward (not (equal ARG '(16))))
        (is-backward (not (equal ARG '(4))))
        (indentation (if (not (current-line-empty-p))
                         (current-indentation)
                       (skip-chars-forward "\s\t\n")
                       (current-indentation))))
    (if (= indentation 0)
        (mark-whole-buffer)
      (if (not is-forward) (push-mark (point) nil t))
      (while (and (not (bobp)) is-backward
                  (or (current-line-empty-p) (<= indentation (current-indentation))))
        (forward-line -1))
      (if is-backward (forward-line 1) (move-beginning-of-line nil))
      (if (not (use-region-p)) (push-mark (point) nil t))
      (while (and (not (eobp)) is-forward
                  (or (current-line-empty-p) (<= indentation (current-indentation))))
        (forward-line 1))
      (if is-forward (backward-char)))))
```